# Type Guard stops working when using an anonymous function/predicate

Tags: typescript

Here's a basic example.

```
type Foo = {
  a?: Record<string, number>; 
}


function processFoo(foo: Foo){

  // Type Guard here
  if (foo.a){ 

    console.log(foo.a); // Is fine here 
    Object.keys(foo.a).forEach((key) => {
        // but not here! 
        foo.a[key] //'foo.a' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)
    })
  }
}
```

Here I use a type guard to check that `foo.a` exists, but TypeScript seems to have forgotten that the property exists by the time the anonymous function comes around.

Is this because technically I could have done something like this:

```
function processFoo(foo: Foo){

  // Type Guard here
  if (foo.a){ 

    console.log(foo.a); // Is fine here 
    Object.keys(foo.a).forEach((key) => {
        // but not here! 
        foo.a[key] //'foo.a' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)
    }); 
    foo.a = undefined; // <--- 
  }
}
```

How would I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way; storing 'foo.a' in a local variable works fine.

```js
type Foo = {
  a?: Record<string, number>;
};

function processFoo(foo: Foo) {
  if (foo.a) {
    const a = foo.a;
    Object.keys(a).forEach(key => {
      a[key];
    });
  }
}
```